# 'CeleryExecutor' is not defined even after pip install airflow[celery]

Tags: python, celery, airflow

I am trying to switch over from LocalExecutor to CeleryExecutor on my local machine. I should have the necessary libraries installed using  `pip install airflow[celery]`. I also have redis installed and running.

However, when I try to run `airflow worker`, I get the error:

```
DEFAULT_EXECUTOR = CeleryExecutor()
NameError:  CeleryExecutor' is not defined
```

I have a `broker url` and `celery_result_backend` both set to `redis://localhost:6379` with redis running in the background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the order of `airflow webserver , airflow scheduler, airflow worker` matters to how this works

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you switched, but airflow doesn't know about it. Check that you have specified *AIRFLOW_HOME* env variable before running each airflow command and you don't have folders *~/airflow* and file *~/airflow.cfg* (in your home directory!) as it will be used as default (ignoring your *AIRFLOW_HOME*).

More details about this issue: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/132

Comment: I have set `executor = CeleryExecutor` in my ~/airflow.cfg. Doesn't this turn on my celery workers for airflow?

Answer (score 1):

Opening up a python shell and run `from celery import Celery` to test if you have installed `celery` already. If not you can install it through pip . 
`pip install celery`

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up a python shell where airflow is installed and run this:

```
>>> from airflow.executors.celery_executor import CeleryExecutor
```

I think you'll get a more useful error.

Comment: I get the same error:
 `DEFAULT_EXECUTOR = CeleryExecutor()
NameError: name 'CeleryExecutor' is not defined`. Seems a bit circular actually

Comment: Hmm what if you try `import celery`? Any errors then?

Comment: `import celery` works for me. I ended up getting it working. It seems like the order of `airflow webserver` , `airflow scheduler`, `airflow worker` works.